# Create a new node from text Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nodes, appendchild

Suppose, I have a text file like this:

```
<button onclick="logIn.newTask();">Log In</button>
```

Now, in Javascript I want to load it in my HTML page with a simply `document.appendChild();` like this:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'http://localhost/button.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.appendChild(client.responseText);   // Load the button see above.
    }
}
client.send();
```

My problem is that this code gives me this error:

[image]

So, I try to find how I can traduce text to node but I can not find anything in this subject.

---

**Short question**:

*I want to load some html's elements in my web page but I can not find any way to achieve this purpose.*

---

Any help is very appreciated.

*Tell me if you have some questions or comments.*

Comment: You don't actually want to append it directly to the `document`, outside `</body>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new DOM node (using `document.createElement(tagName)`), then set its `innerHTML` to your string of HTML.

This will make the browser parse the HTML into child elements of the new node.

You can then append either the new node or its children to some existing node.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try it like:

```
document.appendChild(document.createTextNode(client.responseText));
```

Keep it short and simple.

Comment: He probably wants it to be parsed as HTML.

Comment: or maybe it's just text

Comment: @Slaks, what are the differences?

Comment: @S.P.H.I.N.X: Learn about XSS vulnerabilities and escaping.